# Definition of infimum and supremum in being greater than elements

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose you have a set, $\mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers.The proof by contradiction is simply that you assume.

$a = \sup \mathbb{N}$

The definition of $\sup = a$ would then be that.

$a = \sup \mathbb{N} $

So by definition,

$a \ge n$

But is it also true that?

$a \ge n + \beta$ for any $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: I'm confused what you're question is - are you asking for a hint to finish your proof?

Comment: No, is that property true?

Comment: That isnt what I am asking. I asked, if $a = \sup \mathbb{N}$ then $a \ge n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Will $a \ge n + 1$ as well?

Comment: You have only to ask yourself : *if* $n \in \mathbb N$, *then* $n+1 \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: As per my deleted comment, if $\mathbb N$ is "**the** set of natural numbers", we mean "the set of **all** natural numbers".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to show that there is no largest natural number, but I'm only guessing because the question doesn't seem to clearly state what is to be shown.

I will clean up and finish your proof.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there were some largest natural number $a$, such that $a = \sup \mathbb{N}$. Thus for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $a \geqslant n$. Now by the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) of the set of natural numbers, if $n \in \mathbb{N},$ then $n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$, so we have found an element in $\mathbb{N}$ that is greater than $\sup \mathbb{N}$, so we have a contradiction and thus $\mathbb{N}$ has no greatest element.